# I want to create the widget according to the API response

Tags: flutter

I'm retrieving the API data as below format I made a Model class for that (see below code), in the JSON response `ext` means an extension of the attachment (image or video), So I want to show this response as a **post(like a Facebook post)** I found one method to do that, first counts the image and video (How many images and how many videos) then according to the counts make widgets like Facebook, I'm using `listview.builder()`. but in the `listview.builder()` in one time I can't count images or videos per onetime. **So I want to get the count number how many images? how many videos? using my `ext` in the JSON response**

> see my method

```
List<Attachment> attachmentmodel=widget.newsFeeds.data.data[index].attachment;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int listsize = widget.newsFeeds.data.data.length;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding:  EdgeInsets.only(right: 4,left: 4,top: 4,bottom: 4),
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: listsize,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {

             var allAttachments=widget.newsFeeds.data.data[index].attachment;
             List<Attachment> attachmentmodel=widget.newsFeeds.data.data[index].attachment;

              int textlength = textStatus.length;

              return  AttachmentWidget(attachmentmodel);
);
}
}
```

> Implemented method

```
Widget AttachmentWidget(List<Attachment> attachmentmodel)
  {
    int listsize=attachmentmodel.length;


    return  Container(
      height: 200,
      child: ListView.builder(itemCount: listsize,
      itemBuilder: (context,index)
      {

        return listsize>=5 ? Text('morethan 5 attachments') : Text('less than 5 attachments');
      }),
    );

  }
```

> My JSON

```
"attachment": [
                        {
                            "id": 42,
                            "news_feed_id": 283,
                            "path": "imagepath",
                            "ext": "png",
                            "created_at": "2020-03-19 10:22:26",
                            "updated_at": null,
                            "deleted_at": null
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 43,
                            "news_feed_id": 283,
                            "path": "imagepathf",
                            "ext": "png",
                            "created_at": "2020-03-19 10:22:27",
                            "updated_at": null,
                            "deleted_at": null
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 44,
                            "news_feed_id": 283,
                            "path": "imagepath40a4",
                            "ext": "png",
                            "created_at": "2020-03-19 10:22:27",
                            "updated_at": null,
                            "deleted_at": null
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 45,
                            "news_feed_id": 283,
                            "path": "image path",
                            "ext": "png",
                            "created_at": "2020-03-19 10:22:27",
                            "updated_at": null,
                            "deleted_at": null
                        }
                    ],
```

> This is my model class

```
class Attachment {
  int id;
  int newsFeedId;
  String path;
  dynamic ext;
  DateTime createdAt;
  dynamic updatedAt;
  dynamic deletedAt;

  Attachment({
    this.id,
    this.newsFeedId,
    this.path,
    this.ext,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.deletedAt,
  });

  factory Attachment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Attachment(
    id: json["id"],
    newsFeedId: json["news_feed_id"],
    path: json["path"],
    ext: json["ext"],
    createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
    updatedAt: json["updated_at"],
    deletedAt: json["deleted_at"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "news_feed_id": newsFeedId,
    "path": path,
    "ext": ext,
    "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
    "updated_at": updatedAt,
    "deleted_at": deletedAt,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter a list by using `where`, such as:

```dart
var photos = items.where((media) => isPhoto(media.ext));

var videos = items.where((media) => isVideo(media.ext));

bool isPhoto(String ext) => ext == '.jpg' || ext == '.png';

bool isPhoto(String ext) => ext == '.mp4';
```

Comment: Thank you, I found this method, that is working fine, I think that is the best way to do that I guess.
Thank you, man, for your help

Answer (score 0):

> I think this is the best method to find any of the extensions(png, jpg, jpeg,). **This is working fine for me**

```
Widget AttachmentWidget(List<Attachment> attachmentmodel)
      {
        int listsize=attachmentmodel.length;

        int images=0;
        int videos=0;
        int audio=0;
        int others=0;

        Set <String> ImageExt = {'jpg','png','jpeg','tiff'};
        Set <String> VideoExt = {'mp4','mpeg4','wmp'};
        Set <String> AudioExt={'mpga'};

        for(int i=0;i<=listsize-1;i++)
          {
            String ext=attachmentmodel[i].ext;

            if(ImageExt.contains(ext))
              {
                images=images+1;
              }
            else if(VideoExt.contains(ext))
              {
                videos=videos+1;
              }
            else if(AudioExt.contains(ext))
              {
                audio=audio+1;
              }
            else
              {
                others=others+1;
              }
          }



        return Text('list size    $listsize \n images     $images \n  videos    $videos  \n audios  $audio');
      }
```